# live migration in software defined networks

Tags: sdn

Iam new to the concept of software defined networks and need to know what is exactly is live migration in SDN and how it can be implemented ? also if you can point me to resources about this subject i would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, in a typical data center there are many hosts/servers which house many virtual machines. Consider you want to move/migrate a VM/host from one position to the other. In traditional networking, you would have to manually disconnect the host/VM from the original position, add it to the new position and then update the relevant entries for the network to know that a migration has taken place.

During this process of migration, consider the incoming requests to an application running on that host/VM, all the packets in this time period are lost.

We can overcome this using SDN. When a host/VM migrates to a new position, the controller detects this migration and itself updates the switch/flow table entries to facilitate migration and the network now knows of the new topology. Hence, the packets are not lost in this process as it is almost instantaneous and the term **Live Migration**

To begin with, you will need to understand how to set up topologies using mininet. http://mininet.org/walkthrough/

For the controller implementation I have used POX(Python based). Although several other implementations are out there.
https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki